# How to get value of multi line expression attribute in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

There is illustration in Backbone.Js Cookbook, how to set default values with a multiline expression.

```js
var InvoiceItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    date: function() {
      var date = new Date();
      return date.toISOString();
    }
  }
});
```

However, when I'm trying to access date value as:

```js
var invoiceItemModel = new InvoiceItemModel();
console.log(invoiceItemModel.get('date'));
```

I'm getting this in Google Chrome Console:

[image: Google chrome console output screen]

What is correct way that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to set the date on Invoice creation you need to evaluate the anonymous function to get the `date` value:

```
var InvoiceItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
    date: (function() {
      var date = new Date();
      return date.toISOString();
    })()
  }
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7134/).

Otherwise what you have in `date` attribute is a function that you have to call:

```
var invoiceItemModel = new InvoiceItemModel();
console.log(invoiceItemModel.get('date')());
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7135/).

Answer (score 1):

You can set value using following code:-

```
var invoiceItemModel = new InvoiceItemModel();
invoiceItemModel.set({description:'New Value'});
```

And for get you can use:-

```
 alert(invoiceItemModel.toJSON().description);
```

and you can get date value using this:-

```
console.log(invoiceItemModel.defaults.date());
```

*[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7137/)*

Comment: Hi Mohit, but how to get date value from the model.